# How to resolve Spark Ar upload "opticalFlow" error?

Tags: spark-ar-studio

I've recently started making filters through Spark AR to upload to Instagram. I made a filter, exported, and tried uploading to the Spark AR hub but when uploading my file I received an error message that says

```
"Your File Can't be Uploaded. Your effect uses capabilities which are not supported by the destination chosen on your effect: opticalFlow."
```

I haven't had this issue before and I do not know what `opticalFlow` is and cannot find anything related to it within Spark AR. This error comes up when trying to upload to either Instagram or Facebook.

Has anyone else had this problem and know how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Have just come into this problem too.
Found this that may help:

https://www.scribd.com/document/443006224/Guidelines-For-Spark-AR-Platform

Seems it is to do with the particles.